# MySQL: Consulta dependiendo del valor, no del nombre de la columna

Tags: java, mysql

Mi duda es la siguiente:

Tengo una tabla Mysql de 500 columnas y quiero obtener todos los registros cuyos valores sean diferentes de 100, y despreciar las columnas con ese valor.
Por ejemplo:

```
 Columna1 = 100, Columna2 = 60, Columna3 = 100, Columna4 = 35... Columna  500 = 56
```

solo me interesa las Columnas 2, 4 y 500.

Como en un principio no se el valor de los registros no puedo poner:
`SELECT Columna2, Columna3, Columna500` y como la tabla es muy grande no puedo poner en el `WHERE Columna2 <>100 AND Columna3 <>100 and Columna500 <>100`  además cada fila puede ser distinta.

¿Se os ocurre alguna solución?

Comment: Puedes contextualizar mas el problema? por que tienes 500 columnas?

Comment: Seguro que si pones el código se aclararía lo que ahora mismo no parece tener sentido ¿Qué sentido tiene guardar lo que parece un mismo concepto en 500 columnas distintas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como ya se ha dicho, creo que necesitas pensar tu tabla en vertical (tus 500 columnas en realidad deberían ser 500 filas de una tabla, con **tres columnas... o más, pero ¡no 500! :)** 
Tu pregunta me pareció curiosa, así que me puse a hacer un fiddle de una posible solución.

La consulta te busca cualquier valor que no sea 100 en todas la filas de tu tabla.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/415220/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE columnas
    (`id` int, `columna_num` int, `valor` int)
;

INSERT INTO columnas
    (`id`, `columna_num`, `valor`)
VALUES
    (1,1,100),
    (2,2,60),
    (3,3,100),
    (4,4,35),
    (5,200,100),
    (6,201,100),
    (7,300,100),
    (8,302,100),
    (9,400,100),
    (10,403,100),
    (11,500,56)
;
```

**Query 1 Columnas diferentes de 100:**

```
SELECT
  columna_num, valor
FROM
  columnas
WHERE 
  valor <> 100
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/415220/1/0)**:

> ```
> | columna_num | valor |
> |-------------|-------|
> |           2 |    60 |
> |           4 |    35 |
> |         500 |    56 |
> ```

**Query 2 Todas las columnas hasta 500 (test)** :

```
SELECT
  columna_num, valor
FROM
  columnas
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/415220/2/0)**:

> ```
> | columna_num | valor |
> |-------------|-------|
> |           1 |   100 |
> |           2 |    60 |
> |           3 |   100 |
> |           4 |    35 |
> |         200 |   100 |
> |         201 |   100 |
> |         300 |   100 |
> |         302 |   100 |
> |         400 |   100 |
> |         403 |   100 |
> |         500 |    56 |
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas. Esta mas que una respuesta es una acotación.

Si todas tus 500 columnas usan el mismo tipo de datos, puedes cambiar la estructura de tu tabla. Por lo que entiendo tu tabla debe ser como esta:

```
| id |columna 1 | columna 2 | columna 3 | columna 4 | columna 5 | columna 6 | ...
| 1  |1         | 9         | 6         | 3         | 8         | 4         |
| 2  |2         | 4         | 7         | 2         | 6         | 6         |
| 3  |3         | 9         | 5         | 5         | 5         | 9         |
| 4  |6         | 5         | 12        | 7         | 8         | 9         |
```

Debes entender que cada fila debe tener un identificador único. Entonces puedes transformarla a una tabla como la siguiente:

```
| id | numero_columna | valor
| 1  | 1              | 1
| 1  | 2              | 9
| 1  | 3              | 6
| 1  | 4              | 3
| 2  | 1              | 2
| 2  | 2              | 4
| 2  | 3              | 7
| ...| ...            | ...
```

Donde la primaria tiene la forma `PRIMARY KEY (id, numero_columna)`.

Entonces tu consulta queda como:

```sql
SELECT valor FROM tabla WHERE numero_columna in (2, 4, 500) AND valor <> 100;
```